# Updating TKInter Label via Method in Process

Tags: python, class, process, tkinter

After years of reading this is my first post to Stack Overflow.

I'm writing a Python program and building a front-end with TKInter.  I have a label in my class called label_cpu.  My hope is that I can use the method cpu_counter in a process to update the label with current CPU utilization time.  If I call an instances' method, say GUI.cpu_counter() the label updates, but when I try to start the method via the process.start() it comes up with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris Local/OneDrive/Github/python/gui2.py", line 51, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_tkinter.tkapp'>: attribute lookup tkapp on _tkinter failed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Here's the code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import thread
import sys
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
from tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, Label
from tkinter import StringVar, IntVar

class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        # Configure label for CPU counter/thread
        self.m = StringVar()
        self.m.set("CPU COUNTER GOES HERE")
        self.label_cpu = Label(frame, textvariable = self.m)
        self.button1 = Button(frame, text = "1. Enter Provinces (from Scratch)")
        self.label_cpu.grid(row=1, sticky = W)
        self.button1.grid(row=2, sticky = W)

    def cpu_counter(self):
       while (1 > 0):
            v = str(os.times())
            print(v)
            self.m.set(v)

def cpu_counter_external(GUI):
    #I tried tricking out the process.start() by aiming it here, but 
    #this doesn't work if launched in a process either.
    GUI.cpu_counter()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    menubar = Menu(root)
    menubar.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)
    submenu = Menu(menubar)
    menubar.add_cascade(label = "File!", menu = submenu)
    menubar.add_cascade(label = "Help!", menu = submenu)
    root.config(menu=menubar)
    GUI = MainMenu(root)
    p = Process(target = GUI.cpu_counter)

    #The following line, GUI.cpu_counter() updates the label
    #but it should not be run unless in a process.
    #GUI.cpu_counter()

    p.start()
    p.join()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Tkinter with multiprocessing in this way. Tkinter objects can't be shared between processes.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing is not necessary if I understand what you want to do.  Otherwise use a manager dictionary, see Managng Shared State and Shared Namespaces at Doug Hellman's Pymotw https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html and other places on the web of course.  Post back with a new topic re using a manager dictionary if you want more info on that.

```
from tkinter import *
import thread
import sys
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

## redundant as you already have import *
##from tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, Label
##from tkinter import StringVar, IntVar

class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.ctr=0
        # Configure label for CPU counter/thread
        self.m = StringVar()
        self.m.set("CPU COUNTER GOES HERE")
        self.label_cpu = Label(frame, textvariable = self.m)
        self.button1 = Button(frame, text = "1. Enter Provinces (from Scratch)")
        self.label_cpu.grid(row=1, sticky = W)
        self.button1.grid(row=2, sticky = W)
        self.cpu_counter()

    def cpu_counter(self):
        v = str(os.times())
        print(v, self.ctr)
        self.m.set(v)
        if self.ctr < 100:  ## stop while testing
            self.ctr += 1
            self.master.after(100, self.cpu_counter)

def cpu_counter_external(GUI):
    #I tried tricking out the process.start() by aiming it here, but 
    #this doesn't work if launched in a process either.
    GUI.cpu_counter()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    menubar = Menu(root)
    menubar.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)
    submenu = Menu(menubar)
    menubar.add_cascade(label = "File!", menu = submenu)
    menubar.add_cascade(label = "Help!", menu = submenu)
    root.config(menu=menubar)
    GUI = MainMenu(root)
##    p = Process(target = GUI.cpu_counter)

    #The following line, GUI.cpu_counter() updates the label
    #but it should not be run unless in a process.
    #GUI.cpu_counter()

##    p.start()
##    p.join()
    root.mainloop()
```